# how Frame is displayable even when main thread ended

Tags: java, swing, jframe

After main thread makes a frame it dies but due to non deamon thread created by Event dispatcher machine JVM doesn't exits. But my question is as soon as main thread has ended it's stack will also be gone so reference of frame will be no more so frame object can be garbage collected at any time. But this is not happening why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note: The Swing event thread is a non-daemon thread, and so while it is running, it prevents the application from exiting.

but

> But my question is as soon as main thread has ended it's stack will also be gone so reference of frame will be no more so frame object can be garbage collected at any time.

This is not what makes an object marked for being GC'd. There needs to be no active references to it in active threads, and this condition has not been met due to the EDT.

> An object is eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to that object. References that are held in a variable are usually dropped when the variable goes out of scope. Or, you can explicitly drop an object reference by setting the variable to the special value null. Remember that a program can have multiple references to the same object; all references to an object must be dropped before the object is eligible for garbage collection. [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

---

**Edit**
You state in comment / my replies:

> I mean to say first time the button is clicked ,so its event will go into the event queue ,from there event dispatcher machine will create an EDT for this event which will execute the action performed method.

No. As soon as the GUI is shown, the Swing EDT is created. So if the button is seen in a GUI, then its GUI is being created and shown on the EDT which is running. No EDT will be created when a button is pressed. Instead Runnables may be queued on the event queue to be handled by the EDT.

> Now after execution is done say I press the button again , again the event goes into the event queue , now the machine has to start another thread because the same thread cant be started twice.

Again no. There is only one EDT that continuously runs. No new thread is created *unless you explicitly create and start a new Thread* such as via `new Thread(...).start()`, or by calling `execute()` on a SwingWorker object.

Comment: If I create a frame but not show it then JVM terminates as soon as main thread dies so exactly at what time EDT is created?

Comment: @user2594479: the EDT does not start unless a Swing GUI is rendered and displayed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have one more doubt. I have read that after clicking a button(say) and EDT is created and it executes the code in action performed method , so after executing this code does EDT dies? say if I click the same button twice so the same EDT will execute the method again or a new thread will be started.

Comment: @user2594479: I am confused by your question. If the button is available to be pressed, the EDT is up and running before and after the button has been pressed and after the ActionListener has completed its task.

Comment: I mean to say first time the button is clicked ,so its event will go into the event queue ,from there event dispatcher machine will create an EDT for this event which will execute the action performed method. Now after execution is done say I press the button again , again the event goes into the event queue , now the machine has to start another thread because the same thread cant be started twice.

Comment: @user2594479: I think that you may be confused on how the EDT works. Please see edit to answer above.

Comment: this Object never will be GC'ed, could be reusable in all cases if the JFrame returns true from isDisplayble, edit exception from RepaintManager can change this status to false, never seen another issue (sure maybe exist ...)